# MongoDB: mongoClient instantly closed after open

Tags: java, mongodb

```
package gateways;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Mongodb {

    public MongoDatabase database;

    public Mongodb(){

        Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017")) {
            database = mongoClient.getDatabase("csc207");
            MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection = database.getCollection("users");
        }

    }
}
```

I cannot access my database in other classes since it instantly closed after open.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
```

[I have been searching for this for 2-3 hours, please help me]. I'm using MongoDB Java Driver 4.1.1.

Comment: Find the correct usage in driver documentation, compare to what you are doing, add results of this investigation to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your use of a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. When you open the `mongoClient` in a `try` like that, once you exit the `try` the `close` method of the client is called, shutting down your connection to MongoDB.

From what I see you should be fine without it, so you can can get rid of it and end up with something like this:

```java
public Mongodb() {
    Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    database = mongoClient.getDatabase("csc207");
    MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection = database.getCollection("users");
}
```